# Would like to format the time character by adding zeros in their proper place to format 00:00:00 standard using R

Tags: r, time

For example i have a string that contains time characters like this

```
Time<-c("1:00","15:09","1:06","23:13")
```

I want to turn them into h:m:s

```
Time<-c("01:00:00","15:09:00","01:06:00","23:13:00")
```

Is there a way to do this so I add the zero's in the proper place and also note the original does not have seconds so seconds will be read as zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `as.ITime` from `data.table` does add the seconds

```
library(data.table)
as.ITime(Time)
#[1] "01:00:00" "15:09:00" "01:06:00" "23:13:00"
```

---

Or in `base R` with `as.POSIXct` and `format`

```
format(as.POSIXct(Time, format = '%H:%M'), '%H:%M:%S')
#[1] "01:00:00" "15:09:00" "01:06:00" "23:13:00"
```

Comment: wow didn't expect it as simple. Thank you.